# Yii framework CMultifileupload not working

Tags: yii

I'm trying to implement a multiple file upload using CMultiFileUpload with CUploadedFile, but it doesn't work. Specifically, _POST is not working even considering that I'm using 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' in the options in the view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'examen-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
```

)); ?>

and this is the widget and parameters used for CMultiFileUpload:

```
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'archivo_foto')?>
            <?php //echo CHtml::activeFileField($model,'archivo_foto')?>

            <?php $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'name' => 'archivo_foto',
                    'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png|txt', // useful for verifying files
                    'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
                    'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
                    'max' => 10,
                    'htmlOptions' => array( 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'size' => 25 ),
            )); ?>

            <?php echo $form->error($model,'archivo_foto')?>
    </div>
```

On the other hand, the controller action is implemented this way:

```
        public function actionUpdateam($id)
    {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);
            $dir=Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
            $model->archivo_documento='funciona 0';
            if(isset($_POST['Examen'])) {

                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Examen'];

                    // THIS is how you capture those uploaded images: remember that in your CMultiFile widget, you set 'name' => 'archivo_foto'
                    $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('archivo_foto');

                    // proceed if the images have been set
                    $model->archivo_documento='funciona uno';
                    if (isset($images) && count($images) > 0) {
                            $model->archivo_documento='funciona dos';
                            // go through each uploaded image
                            foreach ($images as $image) {
                                    echo $image->name.'<br />';
                                    $image->saveAs($dir.'/'.$image->name);
                                    $model->archivo_foto = $model->archivo_foto."+".$image->name;
                            }

                            // save the rest of your information from the form
                            if ($model->save()) {
                                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                            }
                    }

            }

            $this->render('update_am',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }
```

And at last, I think that is important to mention the rule used for the model (it might be the cause of the problem as well):

```
array('archivo_foto','file','allowEmpty'=>true,'maxFiles'=>10),
```

I think that the problem is in post method, because the controller is not uploading the files and is not making any changes in the database. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `'htmlOptions'=>array('multiple'=>true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in the Form

```
'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ),
```

Like

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,

     'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same extension and it is wokring for me with these codes
In the view file

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'adpost-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions' => array(
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
     'validateOnChange'=>false,
     'afterValidate'=>'js:submiAjaxForm'
 ),
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
```

)); ?>

```
<?php
                $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
                    'name' => 'photo_name',
                    'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png',
                    'duplicate' => 'File is not existed!',
                    'denied' => 'Not images', // useful,
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'style' =>'color: transparent;',
                    ),
                ));
                ?>
```

And in the contoller

```
$images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('photo_name');
foreach ($images as $image => $pic) {

                        //----------------- Renaming image before uploading

                        $extension      =   $pic->getExtensionName();
                        $newName    =   "image_".$adModel->id;
                        $newName                .=  "_".$imgCount.".".$extension;
                        $imgCount++;

                        if ($pic->saveAs($newPath.$newName)) {
                            // add it to the main model now
                            $img_add             = new AdsPhotosTbl;
                            $img_add->photo_name = $newName;
                            $img_add->ad_id      = $adModel->id;   
                            $img_add->status     = 1;
                            if(!$img_add->save()){
                                $error           =   true;
                                $upload_error    =   true;
                                break;
                            } 
                        }else{
                            $upload_error       =   true;
                            $error              =   true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```